# 'AnyObject' does not have a member named xxx

Tags: swift

There is a method which receives an array of 'AnyObject'. Then inside the method based on some condition cast that AnyObject to specific object. There is no issue till this point. After cast the AnyObject into specific object, if i try to access it's properties then it throws error. I understand the issue for what reason the error is coming. But is there any other way to obtain the same in any other logic. Here is the code.

```
func downloadImage(#list: Array<AnyObject>, forControler: String) {
    var xxxList: Array<AnyObject>

    if forControler == "A" {
        xxxList = list as! Array<A>
    } else if forControler == "B" {
        xxxList = list as! Array<B>
    } else {
        xxxList = list as! Array<C>
    }

    for (index, url) in enumerate(xxxList)  {
        url.A
    }
}
```

Error throws in url.A

Thanks

Comment: The type of the list is determined when you write `var xxxList: Array<AnyObject>`. This does not change as you assign a different type of list to it.

Comment: You have declared it as anyobject. Casting will not change its type

Comment: Yes. i got the issue. any other way that i can read the value of url. Because the rest of the logic are same for all the specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your code.

First, when declaring a var in Swift (here `xxxList`), you have to initialize it just after. Otherwise, this var needs to be flagged as optional.

You get that error for the compiler is "dumb". It does not know what the real type of your objects wrapped into your array is. It only sees `AnyObject` objects, which do not have any `A` field or property. You have to cast your list into the desired type before iterating over it.

Your code should be like this instead:

```
func downloadImage(#list: [AnyObject], forController: String) {
    if forController == "A" {
        var aList = list as! [A]
        // for loop iterating over A objects
    } else if forController == "B" {
        var bList = list as! [B]
        // for loop iterating over B objects
    } else {
        var cList = list as! [C]
        // for loop iterating over C objects
    }
}
```

You must define a loop for each type. Well, you can also define a single loop and perform the casting into that one (moving the `if` statements into that loop).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the xxxList declaration. If i want to have multiple variable and multiple for loops i could have not posted this question. You cannot move the for loop outside as well else the same error will come.